# How to randomize the order of all sublists simultaneously

Tags: r, list

I am looking to randomize the order of the sublists, but retaining the structure. To illustrate, I can do this with a data frame:

```
df1  <-  data.frame("X1" = LETTERS[1:5], "X2" = letters[1:5])
df1

df1R <- df1[sample(df1[,1]),]
df1R

> df1
  X1 X2
1  A  a
2  B  b
3  C  c
4  D  d
5  E  e
> 
> df1R <- df1[sample(df1[,1]),]
> df1R
  X1 X2
2  B  b
5  E  e
1  A  a
3  C  c
4  D  d
```

You can see here that the overall order is randomised, but rows remain together, this is what I mean by retaining the structure - A stays with a, B stays with b...

I'd like to implement this for a list:

```
m1  <- list(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5])
```

But I'm stuck on the how, I've had a good look round but not found a solution. Any advice?

The result would look like:

```
> m1R
[[1]]
[1] "B" "C" "E" "A" "D"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "c" "e" "a" "d"
```

Comment: You could convert the list to a data.frame, apply the randomization, and convert back to a list. No?

Comment: Sure, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution without having to go to a dataframe first - I was using lists to try to avoid dataframes in the first place :D

Comment: Ok. What about my answer then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this to reorder all elements:

```
neworder <- sample.int(5)
lapply(m1, function(x) x[neworder])
```

Comment: Just gives NA's `> lapply(m1, function(x) neworder[x])
[[1]]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA

[[2]]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA`

Comment: @griffinevo Works with me. Same solution, simpler extraction is `lapply(m1, '[', neworder)`.

Comment: @griffinevo I took the `m1` of your post and it works.

Comment: @griffinevo You are doing it the other way aronud, it is **not** `neworder[x]`, it is `x[neworder]`.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! sorry about that - works perfectly (I changed it to match the list names I had in my actual script before testing, sorry!) Thanks very much

Comment: Nice @griffinevo. Rather use `lapply(m1, '[', neworder)`, as suggested by Rui.